# Getting trouble while matching multiple instances of parantheses in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Here's an example of what I'm trying to get:

```
my $a = "This is unsupported slot(s) or slot(s) reserved for another equipment";
my $b = "This is unsupported slot(?s) or slot(?s) reserved for another equipment";
if ($a =~ /$b/) {
  print "yes\n";
} else {
  print "no\n";
}
```

It works (prints yes) as long as **$b = "This is unsupported slot(?s)"**, but doesn't work when there's more than 1 set of parantheses to match.

Comment: You need to escape the parens...

Comment: Use `$a eq $b` to compare strings

Comment: I don't think this example captures enough of what you are trying to do to get you helpful answers.  Can you explain more?  Are you always trying to match literal strings?  Anywhere within the string, or matching the whole thing?  Just one or more than one?  etc.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) is your friend when you need to use literal matching and want to remove the magic from regular expressions.

Comment: Not really. So basically $a will be dynamic entry that will at some point contain $b. (Contain, not necessary be the same). So can't use eq and need to use pattern match

Answer (score 5):

`(?s)` means the rest of the patter matches as if `/s` had been used. You want `$b` to contain `\(s\)`

```
my $b = "This is unsupported slot\\(s\\) or slot\\(s\\)";
   or
my $b = qr/This is unsupported slot\(s\) or slot\(s\)/;
```

Comment: Or if the `(s)` is optional, `(?:\(s\))?`